# Scrapy- extract an image

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract an image from the site  http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Wirko-Ind-Black-Sneakers-187839.html using x-path:

```
item['pimg'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/img').extract()
```

I'm getting text value.I want to know how I can store an image. Please help.

Comment: All images are string values, open up any image in "notepad" and you'll see a image is basically just a long garbage string that image viewers can interprate. Try:  `with open('myimage.jpg', 'wb') as fh: ` and then `fh.write(image_string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
item['pimg'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/img').extract()
counter = 0
for image_data in item['pimg']:
    with open('image_' + str(counter) + '.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
        fh.write(image_data)
    counter += 1
```

Assuming `item['pimg']` contains the image-string in a list format and that you're ok with the file-naming.

Comment: I'm getting this error :
exceptions.TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list(fh.write(item['pimg'])

Comment: try `print([item['pimg']])`and you should get quite a good understanding of why this error pops up. Get back to me if that "debug" information didn't solve your issue. Seeing how i don't know what `hxs.select` spits out, i guess however that it's a list of image-data for each image it found such as `('image-1-garbage-string', 'image-2-garbage-string', ...)`

Comment: the script ran successfully;The file was also created(image_0),  however, its not readable

Comment: Is it even a JPG image? or even a proper image data you've extracted with your "regexp"? Open the file with notepad, compare it with the string you've reiceved from `hxs.select` because i'm not sure you've got the proper data in the first place.

Comment: the extension of the file was jpg. And after opening the file with notepad, I got the following content:
<img data-js-function="setPlaceholderOnError" data-placeholder="http://static.jabong.com/images/core/placeholder/no-image-small.jpg" alt="Buy Puma Wirko Ind. Black Sneakers" src="http://static.jabong.com/images/product_detail/placeholder-gallery.png" class="gallerySprite" style="background-position:-0px 0px;" width="37" height="54">

It's the same that I received from hxs.select earlier .

Comment: What does `print([item['pimg']])` say, what does the original image (if saved with FireFox/Chrome and opened with notepad) say and what does my code say? Where's the differences?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use the images pipeline: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html

But remember that the `image_urls` field must have a list of fully qualified URLs. So, you should use something like

```
from urlparse import urljoin

    # ... this in your callback method

    item['image_urls'] = []

    for img in hxs.select('//img'):  # change the xpath to suit your needs
        # img is a selector object, select() always returns a list,
        # this might raise the exception IndexError in case the img element
        # does not have a src attribute.
        path = img.select('@src').extract()[0]
        item['image_urls'].append(urljoin(response.url, path))
```

If you followed the example in the documentation, the field `images` will contain the metadata for each image: checksum, path, url.